# How to buy a website

Tags: ecommerce

I am in the market to buy a website. I would like to browse a list of websites that are for sale or up for auction. Are there any good services for this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'website'? Do you mean a domain name (www.example.com) or hosting or both?

Comment: I mean both the domain name and the website. Do you know of any?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to purchase both a domain name, and the hosting to put the website online, I'd advise purchasing them from separate companies (personal preference) unless you find a really good deal for both and have read multiple reviews on the quality of their hosting/customer service.

A good place to check out for your domain name first would be [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/) or [123reg](http://www.123-reg.co.uk/), as although I personally wouldn't say they're that great for hosting, they do some pretty good deals on domain names and you can find a wide range of extensions available too.

For hosting however, the choices range far and wide. I don't personally know the reputation of hosting companies over there in the USA, but there's one in the UK called [TSOHost](https://www.tsohost.com/) that I'd recommend - my websites always seem to be up, and if I do have a query they always answer me within a few hours.

All three of the previous companies I've stated provide you the option of using WordPress and other types of plugins if you're interested in getting a website built fast without having to do much of the back-end coding.

**Edit**

In the case of wanting to buy an already established website, [Flippa](https://flippa.com/buy) is probably your best bet.

Comment: Just to make it clear. I am not interested in buying hosting I am interested in buy an actual website - not web hosting. For example, if stackexchange was for sale they would post it on a website selling service so other people can buy the domain and the website. Is it possible to buy a website like this?

Comment: Oh. In that case you can just use https://flippa.com/buy